# Populate HTML dropdown menu from column in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, drop-down-menu, google-sheets

I´m new to .gs so this should not be difficult.

I have a Google Spreadsheet with values in a column (Lets say column A).
I have created a custom menu using .gs where the user will select an option.

Clicking one of the options (new component) a popup appears with a dropdown menu where user should select from the values.

**CustomMenu.gs**

```
 function onOpen() {
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
 ui.createMenu('bq Library Menu')
  .addItem('Add new component', 'newComponent')
  .addSeparator()
  .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Modify existing component')
      .addItem('Remove component', 'removeComponent'))
  .addToUi();
 }

 function newComponent() {

 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('NewComponentForm')
     .setWidth(400)
     .setHeight(300);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
     .showModalDialog(html, 'New Component Form');
 }
```

**NewComponentForm.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Select manufacturer from the list</p>

  <div class="dropdown">
     <button onclick="loadManufacturers()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
     <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

I want the dropdown menu to show all elements in column A from the spreadsheet. I´ve tried several options but have not obtained the required result.

So, how do I need to proceed to implement the dropdown populating process?

Answer (score 3):

- You want to create a select box and put the values from the column "A" of Spreadsheet.
- When a value from the select box is selected, you want to retrieve the value.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation, so please think of this as just one of them.

The flow of this modified script is as follows.

1. Open a dialog.
2. Click "Dropdown" button.
3. By `google.script.run`, run the function of `getValuesFromSpreadsheet()` at Google Apps Script side.
4. At `getValuesFromSpreadsheet()`, the values are retrieved from Spreadsheet and returned to Javascript.
5. At `withSuccessHandler()`, the returned values are retrieved. Using the values, a select box is created.
6. When a value of the select box is selected, `selected()` is run and retrieved the selected value.

When above flow is reflected, the modified script is as follows.

#### GAS:

Please add the following Google Apps Script to `CustomMenu.gs`.

```
function getValuesFromSpreadsheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  return sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues(); // Retrieve values and send to Javascript
}
```

- In this sample script, the values are retrieved from "Sheet1" of the active Spreadsheet. The values are in the column "A".

  - If you want to retrieved from other range and sheet, please modify this.

#### HTML:

Please add the following Javascript to `NewComponentForm.html`.

```
<script>
  function loadManufacturers() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
      let select = document.createElement("select");
      select.id = "select1";
      select.setAttribute("onchange", "selected()");
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").appendChild(select);
      ar.forEach(function(e, i) {
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = i;
        option.text = e;
        document.getElementById("select1").appendChild(option);
      });
    }).getValuesFromSpreadsheet();
  };

  function selected() {
    const value = document.getElementById("select1").value;
    console.log(value);
  }
</script>
```

- Use `google.script.run` for retrieving the values from Spreadsheet.
- Using `withSuccessHandler`, retrieve the values from Google Apps Script.
- When "Dropdown" button is clicked, a select box is created.
- The selected value can be seen at console.

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify it for your situation.

#### References:

- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [withSuccessHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))

If I misunderstood your question, I'm sorry.